# Upload SQL Dump File Through PHP error

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a newbie programmer in PHP, and I have a problem..

I try to upload a SQL dump file (*.sql) to the database using PHP, but an error occured.. here's my code :

```
<?php

$eror       = false;
$folder     = './upload/';

$file_type  = array('sql');
$max_size   = 1000000; // 1MB

if(isset($_POST['btnUpload'])){
//Mulai memorises data
$file_name  = $_FILES['data_upload']['name'];
$file_size  = $_FILES['data_upload']['size'];
//cari extensi file dengan menggunakan fungsi explode
$explode    = explode('.',$file_name);
$extensi    = $explode[count($explode)-1];

//check apakah type file sudah sesuai
if(!in_array($extensi,$file_type)){
    $eror   = true;
    $pesan .= '- Type file yang anda upload tidak sesuai<br />';
}
if($file_size > $max_size){
    $eror   = true;
    $pesan .= '- Ukuran file melebihi batas maximum<br />';
}
//check ukuran file apakah sudah sesuai

if($eror == true){
    echo '<div id="eror">'.$pesan.'</div>';
}
else{
    //mulai memproses upload file
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['data_upload']['tmp_name'], $folder.$file_name)){
        //catat nama file ke database
            $f = fopen($file_name,"r+");
            $sqlFile = fread($f, filesize($file_name));
            $sqlArray = explode(';',$sqlFile);
            foreach ($sqlArray as $stmt) {
              if (strlen($stmt)>3 && substr(ltrim($stmt),0,2)!='/*') {
                $result = mysql_query($stmt);
                if (!$result) {
                  $sqlErrorCode = mysql_errno();
                  $sqlErrorText = mysql_error();
                  $sqlStmt = $stmt;
                  break;
                }
              }
            }
            if ($sqlErrorCode == 0) {
              echo "Script is executed succesfully!";
            } else {
              echo "An error occured during installation!<br/>";
              echo "Error code: $sqlErrorCode<br/>";
              echo "Error text: $sqlErrorText<br/>";
              echo "Statement:<br/> $sqlStmt<br/>";
            }
            }
     }
   }
 ?>
```

and it show and error like this :

```
Warning: fopen(test.sql): failed to open stream: No such file or directory    in C:\xampp\htdocs\tampung\action_upload.php on line 36

Warning: filesize(): stat failed for test.sql in C:\xampp\htdocs\tampung\action_upload.php on line 37

Warning: fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\tampung\action_upload.php on line 37

Notice: Undefined variable: sqlErrorCode in C:\xampp\htdocs\tampung\action_upload.php on line 50
Script is executed succesfully!
```

can you tell me what's wrong?

Best Regards

Comment: This has nothing to do with mysql . This is purely a PHP file upload error. But you shouldn't be importing SQL data in this manner. You should to so directly in the mysql console.

Comment: Problem is with reading file as i can see in error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to give the full path of the moved file:

```
$f = fopen($folder.$file_name,"r+");
$sqlFile = fread($f, filesize($folder.$file_name));
```